# Best tool to find an optimal option?

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes

I like to sell uncovered put options, using my valuation of the company as the strike price. I'm looking for a tool that takes stock identifier and strike price as input and outputs the optimal expiration date, i.e. one that has the highest ratio of option price to days until expiration. Can anybody suggest anything?

Comment: Do you literally just want to divide the option price by number of days?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

This makes little sense. An option with the same strike, does not get much more expensive if you add a day to expiration. However, if you divide by the number of days, you reduce the value of the option significantly every day....

Example in Python (using standard Black Scholes Merton, thus ignoring that deep ITM puts, in the presence of positive interest rates $r>0$, can be subject to early exercise):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

def BSM(S,K,r,d,t, sigma, cp_flag):
    d1 = ((np.log(S/K) + (r - d + 0.5 * sigma **2) * t) / (sigma * np.sqrt (t)))
    d2 = d1 - sigma * np.sqrt(t) 
    opt = cp_flag*S *np.exp(-d*t)* norm.cdf(cp_flag*d1) - cp_flag* K * np.exp(-r*t)  * norm.cdf(cp_flag*d2)
    return opt

pd.DataFrame(zip([i for i in range(1,365)], [BSM(100,100,0,0,i/365, 0.3, -1) for i in range(1,365)],  [BSM(100,100,0,0,i/365, 0.3, -1)/i for i in range(1,365)]), columns=['Days','Put Value', 'Put/Days'])
```

[image]

[image]

This simple example even ignores that IV is usually flattening with increased maturity (which will make the longer tenors comparatively cheaper). For example, the 165 strike Apple put option expiring on 14th of April (8 days as of the last available price) costs ~ USD 2.1 at the time of writing:  $2.1/8 = 0.2625$.
The one expiring on 18th of August (134 days) costs ~ USD 10. $10/134 = 0.0746$.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a tool that uses real option price, not theoretical one. As for the sense of what I want to achieve, I really know what I'm doing. I don't trade options, I just sell puts at a fixed (per company) strike price and wait until expiration, so the simple price/time ratio is all I need to find the optimal choice.

Comment: The values I provided were real option values from the exchange. It should be clear that it makes no sense what you try to do, given my examples. The highest ratio is always the one with the shortest time to expiry. Also, any place where you get the option value and the expiry date will be sufficient to do to this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't analyze this code. But if you use real option price, why do you compute BSM theoretical price? Besides, it's not always true that a shorter expiration date will yield higher price/time ratio, and if you include commissions in your calculations, it's almost never true.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else wanting to achieve the same thing, here's a custom tool I've created:

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime


def read_input_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        return [tuple(line.strip().split()) for line in lines]

def calculate_best_expiration(ticker, strike_price, commission):
    ticker_data = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    expirations = ticker_data.options
    prices_per_day = []
    for expiration in expirations:
        data = ticker_data.option_chain(date=expiration).puts
        data = data[data['lastTradeDate'].notnull()]
        data = data[data['strike'] == float(strike_price)]
        days_to_expiration = (datetime.fromisoformat(expiration) - datetime.today()).days
        if len(data) > 0 and days_to_expiration > 0:
            ask = data['ask'].iloc[0]
            bid = data['bid'].iloc[0]
            price = (bid + ask) / 2 * 100 - commission
            prices_per_day.append(price / days_to_expiration)
        else:
            prices_per_day.append(np.nan)
    best_expiration_index = int(np.nanargmax(prices_per_day))
    return expirations[best_expiration_index], prices_per_day[best_expiration_index]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_data = read_input_file('input.txt')
    commission = 2.1  # flat fee per contract in USD

    for ticker, strike_price in input_data:
        try:
            (best_expiration, ratio) = calculate_best_expiration(ticker, strike_price, commission)
            print(f'{ticker} ({strike_price}): {best_expiration}, USD ${ratio:.3f}/day/contract')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error while processing {ticker} ({strike_price}): {e}')
```

The expected input file format is:

```
AAPL 100
INTC 25
...
```